# Hi, how to delete the files in AWS based on date in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i am trying to delete the files in AWS BASED ON DATE,
GEtting the Below Error:
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Key, value: 2021-06-30, type: <class 'datetime.date'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
Here is my code.

```
def post(self, request):
    try:
        log_request(request)
        company_id = request.data.get('company_id')
        execute_function = query_executer(company_id)
        # s3bucket_path = request.data.get('ip_path')
        # date = request.data.get('ip_modified_date')
        use_date =  datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days = 5)

        s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_AccessKeyId,
                          aws_secret_access_key=settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_SecretAccessKey)

        response = s3.delete_object(Bucket=settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_NAME, Key=use_date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`use_date` is a date and you use it in `Key=use_date`. A string is expected here. You can turn it to string like `Key=str(use_date)` (assuming you have an object in the bucket with this name)

Comment: In AWS have the date format as: June 30, 2021, 19:47:09 (UTC+05:30) but in my local getting as:2021-06-30, its going to return but the files are not  deleting, should i change the conversations? @balderman

Comment: The `Key` you pass is the name of the Object that you want to delete. So there should be an exact match.

Comment: try to run the code not throwing any error even the files are not deleted in my AWS .